# How do I activate scrolling on my trackpad?

Tags: 11.10, trackpad

I have an Acer Aspire  5738, and the trackpad allows for scrolling. It worked in Natty and Maverick, but doesn't work on my fresh installation of Oneiric stable. How do I get this to work?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was fixed in Precise. I cannot ascertain why.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings > Mouse and Touchpad and click on the Touchpad tab. In the Scrolling section you should be able to set it to scroll however it did before.

Comment: I have tried that. It makes no difference whatever.